# Why is my React date picker CSS failing on compile?

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I am using `react-datepicker` in my NPM project and while compiling I am getting this error. I am adding the component code along with this.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.module.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[6].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[6].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.module.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Missing whitespace before :global
    at D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\react-datepicker\dist\react-datepicker.module.css:485:1
    at transform (D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\postcss-modules-local-by-default\src\index.js:35:13)
    at D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\postcss-modules-local-by-default\src\index.js:79:44
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Selector.map (D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\selectors\container.js:347:23)
    at transform (D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\postcss-modules-local-by-default\src\index.js:79:25)
    at D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\postcss-modules-local-by-default\src\index.js:153:15
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Pseudo.map (D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\selectors\container.js:347:23)
    at transform (D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\postcss-modules-local-by-default\src\index.js:152:29)
    at D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\postcss-modules-local-by-default\src\index.js:79:44
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Selector.map (D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\selectors\container.js:347:23)
    at transform (D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\postcss-modules-local-by-default\src\index.js:79:25)
    at D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\postcss-modules-local-by-default\src\index.js:54:15
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at transform (D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\postcss-modules-local-by-default\src\index.js:46:31)
    at Processor.func (D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\postcss-modules-local-by-default\src\index.js:238:5)
    at Processor._runSync (D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\processor.js:102:26)
    at Processor.processSync (D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\processor.js:197:23)
    at localizeNode (D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\postcss-modules-local-by-default\src\index.js:239:6)
    at D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\postcss-modules-local-by-default\src\index.js:511:29
    at D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:96:18
    at D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:55:18
    at Root.each (D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:41:16)
    at Root.walk (D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:52:17)
    at Root.walkRules (D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:94:19)
    at Object.Once (D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\postcss-modules-local-by-default\src\index.js:501:16)
    at LazyResult.runOnRoot (D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:337:23)
    at LazyResult.runAsync (D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:393:26)
    at LazyResult.async (D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:221:30)
    at LazyResult.then (D:\SNehil\Travelocity\wander-world\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:206:17)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I have tried out checking the `dist` folder location and it is correct.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.module.css'

function DateInput() {
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(null);

  const handleDateChange = date => {
    setSelectedDate(date);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="date-input">Choose a date:</label>
      <br />
      <DatePicker
        id="date-input"
        selected={selectedDate}
        onChange={handleDateChange}
        dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
        showMonthDropdown
        showYearDropdown
        dropdownMode="select"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default DateInput;
```